# Calculus 1: Limits at negative infinity of quotients with square root, why introduce a negative when trying to simply

Tags: calculus, factoring, limits-without-lhopital, infinity, conjunctive-normal-form

Why do we introduce a negative when trying to simplify? (circled in orange)
If x approaches -$\infty$ for both, the negative sign should cancel out..?

Khan acad's working:
[image]

Edit, removed my workings as requested & added a follow up: Why don't they do the same here?
[image]

Comment: As mentioned, "Since for negative values, $x^3=-\sqrt{x^6}$." Besides, the numerator goes to $+\infty$ while the denominator goes to $-\infty$. And don't forget to simplify the fraction.

Comment: Please spare us the crappy draft. Learn to typeset with MathJax.

Comment: Hi @player3236, I understand the radical cannot be negative, but it's not connecting for some reason, why we are using $-\sqrt{x^6}$ instead. Isn't multiplying the limit by $\frac{-\sqrt{x^6}}{x^3}$ akin multiplying the whole thing by -1, there by changing the whole equation? I suspect it's my weak algebra, radical or factorizing failing me here? Is there a non-calculus video of example somewhere to help me understand this?

Comment: Again, the point is that $x$ is negative. Consider $x=-2$, then $$\frac {-\sqrt{x^6}}{x^3}=\frac {-\sqrt{64}}{-8}=\frac {-8}{-8}=1$$

Comment: I see, this makes sense, but why do they not apply it for the other question..?

Comment: I have added the follow up part as well(edited the original question), why are't we adding negative for that question?

Comment: "removed my workings as requested" -- Nobody asked for that. Someone asked you to make the workings more readable. The how-to instructions start here: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation (No need to fix it here, now; but think about it for the next question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be helpful to look at the facts/steps all separately:

#### Square root of a square

For any real number $a$ (negative or not), $a^{2}$ is nonnegative,
so we can take the square root of it; $\sqrt{a^{2}}$ makes sense.
And the square root function always outputs a nonnegative number.

If $a\ge0$, then $\sqrt{a^{2}}=a$. And if $a<0$, $\sqrt{a^{2}}$
is positive but $a$ is not; we have $\sqrt{a^{2}}=-a$. Combining
these two cases together, we have $\boxed{\sqrt{a^{2}}=\left|a\right|}$ for
any real $a$. I think that equation is worth memorizing.

#### Problem 1

In the first problem presented, we have $\sqrt{x^{6}}=\sqrt{\left(x^{3}\right)^{2}}=\left|x^{3}\right|$.
Since we're taking a limit as $x\to-\infty$, we only care about negative
values of $x$. And the cube of a negative value is negative (e.g. $\left(-2\right)^{3}=-2*4=-8$). When we have the absolute value of
a negative number, we negate it to make it positive. So *in this context*,
$\left|x^{3}\right|=-\left(x^{3}\right)$. The order of operations
lets us drop the parentheses. So we have $\sqrt{x^{6}}=-x^{3}$ in
this context, and can multiply through by $-1$ to get $x^{3}=-\sqrt{x^{6}}$.

Thus, $1=\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{-\sqrt{x^{6}}}}{\dfrac{1}{x^{3}}}$, which
helps you solve the limit.

#### Problem 2

In the second problem presented, we have $\sqrt{x^{4}}=\sqrt{\left(x^{2}\right)^{2}}=\left|x^{2}\right|$.
Since we're taking a limit as $x\to-\infty$, we only care about negative
values of $x$. But the square of a negative value is positive (e.g.
$\left(-2\right)^{2}=4$). When we have the absolute value of a positive
number, we just get the original number. So in this context, $\left|x^{2}\right|=x^{2}$.
In fact, since the square of a nonnegative number is nonnegative,
we would still have $\left|x^{2}\right|=x^{2}$ when $x$ is nonnegative,
too. So we have $\sqrt{x^{4}}=x^{2}$ for any real $x$.

Thus, $1=\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^{4}}}}{\dfrac{1}{x^{2}}}$,
which helps you solve the limit.

Comment: Yes this is way more readable than mine. Thank you Mark!

Answer (score 1):

If $x<0$, $\sqrt{x^2}=x$ is false and for the same reason $\sqrt{x^6}=x^3$ as well.

Comment: I understand the radical cannot be negative, but it's not connecting for some reason, why we are using $-\sqrt{x^6}$ instead. Isn't multiplying the limit by $\frac{-\sqrt{x^6}}{x^3}$ akin multiplying the whole thing by -1, there by changing the whole equation? I suspect it's my weak algebra, radical or factorizing failing me here? Is there a non-calculus video of example somewhere to help me understand this?

Comment: @olif9837: do you understand my answer ? What are the correct identities ?

Comment: understand that x cannot be negative. Are you saying $\sqrt{x^6}$ is false too?

Comment: @olif9837 Yes, Yves is indeed saying "for $x<0$, $\sqrt{x^6}=x^3$ is false".

Comment: @olif9837: I never said that $x$ cannot be negative ! On the opposite, I said "when $x$ is negative..."

Comment: @olif9837: "$\sqrt{x^6}$ is false" has no meaning.

Comment: Yep, I had a breakthrough, what a feeling! Yep got it @MarkS. , $\sqrt{x^6} = x^{3} = -\infty$, when x subbed for $-\infty$

Answer (score 0):

I got it! It is because I need to ensure that I'm multiplying by 1. Thanks for all the help along the way. It pushed me to go back to revise exponentials. Two step forward one step back they say!

[image]